# Url redirect ajax call quotes within quotes

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, syntax-error, quote

I'm populating a list from an ajax call including a button that will have a unique id assigned to it to redirect to a page.

The problem I'm having is that there is so many quotations in it that it's not reading properly

```
  row.append("<td><button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("UserForm\\{" + user[i].id +"", "Request")'" >Edit</button</td>);
```

I've tried a few different variations of the quotation marks but having no luck.

Please help.

UPDATE:

I've got it to work for the general redirect but without the unique id by changing quotes to back ticks:

```
row.append(`<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("UserForm",  "Request")'" />`);
```

I'm still however needing to add on /{user[i].id} after UserForm. Having no luck adding a variable into it without causing syntax issues.

userform source code:

```
[RoutePrefix("Request")]
public class NewUserController : Controller
{
        [Route("UserForm")]
        [CustomAuthorize(Roles = UserRole.Any)]
        public ActionResult ManagerNewUserForm()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Request/UserForm.cshtml");
        }
}
```

Comment: View source in the browser, and share the _generated_ HTML here so we can see what it outputs.

Comment: `UserForm{` where is the matching `}`?

Comment: @mjwills <button  onclick="location.href=" request userform ''>Edit</button>

Comment: That was from `View source` specifically? How _exactly_ did you get that string?

Comment: That is from the view source

Comment: How _exactly_ did you get that view source? Be as detailed as possible. _I ask since I don't think you got that from View source - I think you got it from the developer tools (which is different). Since the code you showed is very unlikely to have generated that HTML._

Comment: @mjwills actually, I've copied the above wrong. I can't even add my user id into the onclick without it throwing an error. If I just do "UserForm", "Request" to try and get that link, this is what is in the page source: row.append("<td><button onclick='location.href='/Request/UserForm/' ' >Edit</button></td>");

Comment: Please show us the `UserForm` action method source code.

Comment: @mjwills see edits above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

So I was mixing html and cshtml up.

the solution that worked:

```
 row.append("<a class='btn btn-default' href='" + '@Url.Action("UserForm", "Request")' + user[i].Id + "'>Edit</a>");
```